# C# - Export .pfx certificate and import it later as a file

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate2

I basically need to export a `.pfx` certificate as a `Base64string`, store it in a database and recover it later, converting from `Base64string`.
What I'm using at the moment is the `X509Certificate2` class like the following:

To convert it and store in DB the cert64 string:

```
X509Certificate2 pfx = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\originalcert.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);

string cert64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pfx.RawData);
```

And get it later from DB (I need to store it as a Base64string):

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(string64cert), "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\copycert.pfx", cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "password"));
```

And it returns true when I compare `C:\originalcert.pfx` and `C:\copycert.pfx` using:

```
X509Certificate2.Equals
```

For the application I'm running that requires a certificate to work properly, I sometimes get an error with some different `.pfx` certificates provided to me that I use to work around importing/installing to the machine and exporting it via web browser, creat a new `.pfx` file and voilà.

Using the `copycert.pfx` file gives me the same error but when I try to install `copycert.pfx` through the file or import it using a web browser I get: "The import was successful" message, but can't find the installed certificate under the "Personal" tab as I would if I installed the original `originalcert.pfx`.

Also, it is important that I export from a `.pfx` file and import it later to a `.pfx` file.

What am I doing wrong/is missing in the code export/import?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your solution doesn't ever work in a manner you describe. Here is why:

`string cert64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pfx.RawData);`

this line converts only **public** part of the certificate. No private key information is ever stored in `RawData` property. This means that you can't restore original PFX from this string. What you really should do is to read contents of the file and convert it to Base64 string without touching `X509Certificate2` class. Replace first two lines of posted code with these two:

```
Byte[] rawCert = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\originalcert.pfx");
String cert64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

PFX certificates support only pure binary encoding (i.e. PFX cannot be stored in PEM format), so just read raw bytes and convert them.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(string64cert), "password", 
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | 
    X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | 
    X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
```

this command only imports certificate to an `X509Certificate2` object and installs private key to CSP specified in PFX (or to default CSP if no provider information is stored in PFX). In order to install it to personal store, you need to do that:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Certificates.Add(cert);
store.Close();
```

starting with .NET 4.6, `X509Store` implements `IDisposable`, so you should use `using` clause to dispose the object:

```
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)) {
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(cert);
}
```

**Note** that the code above is necessary only to install certificate to certificate store. In order to restore it from database to PFX file, just save binary data to a file:

```
Byte[] rawCert = Convert.FromBase64String(string64cert);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\copycert.pfx");
```

### Summary

Just to summarize all written. To convert PFX to Base64 string:

```
Byte[] rawCert = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\originalcert.pfx");
String cert64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

to restore PFX from Base64 string and save to a file:

```
Byte[] rawCert = Convert.FromBase64String(string64cert);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\copycert.pfx");
```

Comment: Thanks!
I'm already doing exactly this to store xml files, I don't know why, but some time ago I tried doing that and it didn't work out to me, and figured certificates didn't worked in such a simple manner like I was doing with my xml files.

Comment: Is this only for Windows and .NET Framework?  Or is it the same for .NET 5+ on Linux?

Comment: This applies to .NET Core and .NET 5+ on Linux. Code snippets are platform independent.